# How do I get an equivalent of /dev/one in Linux

Tags: linux, file, bash

You can use

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file count=1024 bs=1024
```

to **zero** fill a file.

Instead of that I want to **one** fill a file. How do I do that?

There is **no** `/dev/one` file, so how can I simulate that effect via on bash shell?

Comment: Write a C program to do it, should be trivial.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
dd if=<(yes $'\01' | tr -d "\n") of=file count=1024 bs=1024
```

Substitute `$'\377'` or `$'\xFF'` if you want all the bits to be ones.

MacOS `tr` may complain about "Illegal byte sequence". Setting `LC_CTYPE=C` will prevent that. This version can also be used in Linux:

```
dd if=<(yes $'\01' | LC_CTYPE=C tr -d "\n") of=file count=1024 bs=1024
```

Comment: For others: on macOS you will need to set environment variable LANG="C" to get `tr` to behave in the way that makes this command work

Comment: @MattSephton: I just tested it on MacOS Sierra and it works fine for me without changing `LANG` (mine is en_US.UTF-8).

Comment: Interesting. I was changing \00 to \xFF and was getting something other than \xFF until I used LANG="C"

Comment: @MattSephton: Anything `\x80` or above. Evidently it doesn't like the 8th bit set unless `LANG=C`. For those that might not be aware, you can do that for just the environment of `tr`: `dd if=<(yes $'\xFF' | LANG=C tr -d "\n") of=file count=1024 bs=1024` and it doesn't affect the general environment.

Comment: This gives me an error of: `dd: failed to open '/dev/fd/63': No such file or directory`

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: Did you run it using `sudo`? That's one possible reason for that error. If so, then this is one way to make it work: `sudo bash -c 'dd if=<(yes $'\01' | tr -d "\n") of=file count=1024 bs=1024'`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson yes was using sudo. The `bash -c ...` works however!

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: The process substitution creates a file descriptor which `sudo` then closes making it unavailable. Wrapping the whole thing in `bash -c` delays the creation of the file descriptor until after `sudo` starts.

Comment: `$'\xFF'` gave me `0x78`-bytes. `$'\377'` gave me correctly `0xFF`-bytes.

Comment: @GolarRamblar: `0x78` is "x" (lowercase x) so perhaps you omitted the backslash.

Answer (score 41):

```
tr '\0' '\377' < /dev/zero | dd bs=64K of=/dev/sdx
```

This should be much faster. Choose your blocksizes (or add counts) like you need at. Writing ones to a SSD-Disk till full with a blocksize of 99M gave me 350M/s write performance.

Comment: I confirm this is at least twice as fast as the accepted solution.  However I didn't notice any noticeable performance improvement from varying the blocksize (though there is a huge decrease of performance without the bs argument).

Comment: Thanks. I successfully used this modified command to one-fills my 2GB micro SD:
`tr '\0' '\377' < /dev/zero | pv | sudo dd bs=512K of=/dev/sdx` with speed ~8MB/s.
The command `pv` shows you how many bytes are done, and the speed. You may need to install it, but it's very useful.

Comment: @JohnnyWong: Adding `status=progress` to the arguments of `dd` gives a throughput measure output directly by `dd`.

Comment: Note that `tr` conversions depend on the locale — `\377` may not be all `1` bits, for example on Mac with the `en_US.UTF-8` locale, this encodes `bfc3 bfc3 bfc3…`. To get all ones consistently, you could set: `env LC_ALL=C tr '\000' '\377'`

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could do this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=1024 bs=1024 |
  tr '\000' '\001' > file
```

Comment: One fill would be '\377', no?

Comment: Hmm, I guess it depends on what you want.  This will fill a file with bytes of value `1` (`01 01 01 01 ...`).  Using `\377` gets you all *bits* set to 1 (so `FF FF FF FF ...`).  Depends on the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
pv /dev/zero |tr \\000 \\377 >targetfile
```

...where `\377` is the octal representation of `255` (a byte with all bits set to one).  Why `tr` only works with octal numbers, I don't know -- but be careful not to subconsciously translate this to **3FF**.

---

The syntax for using `tr` is error prone.  I recommend verifying that it is making the desired translation...

```
cat /dev/zero |tr \\000 \\377 |hexdump -C
```

Note: [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) is a nice utility that replaces `cat` and adds a progress/rate display.

Comment: Note: If you are trying to fill an entire device, it's probably better to avoid `dd` since that will slow things down (by a lot) if you don't manually select an optimum `bs` value.

Comment: `pv` will also give an estimate of time remaining if it has enough information to do so.

Comment: While you're at it, maybe prefix with `time` and `nice`.

Answer (score 1):

I created a device driver in my [github](https://github.com/tinmarino/dev_one). Installing it creates a file `/dev/one` that is writing only bits set to 1.

The c file called one.c (the only interesting part is in `device_file_read`):

```c
// File Driver to create a devince /dev/one like the /dev/zero

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int device_file_major_number = 0;
static const char device_name[] = "one";

static ssize_t device_file_read(
        struct file *file_ptr,
        char __user *user_buffer,
        size_t count,
        loff_t *position) {
    printk( KERN_NOTICE "One: Device file is read at offset = %i, read bytes count = %u\n" , (int)*position , (unsigned int)count );

    // Allocate Kernel buffer
    char* ptr = (char*) vmalloc(count);

    // Fill it with one, byte per byte
    // -- Note that byte is the smallest accesible data unit
    memset(ptr, 0xFF, count);

    char res = copy_to_user(user_buffer, ptr, count);
    if (res != 0){ return -EFAULT; }

    // Return number of byte read
    return count;
}

static struct file_operations simple_driver_fops = {
    .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
    .read    = device_file_read,
};

int register_device(void) {
    int res = 0;
    printk( KERN_NOTICE "One: register_device() is called.\n" );
    res = register_chrdev( 0, device_name, &simple_driver_fops );
    if( res < 0 ) {
        printk( KERN_WARNING "One:  can\'t register character device with error code = %i\n", res );
        return res;
    }
    device_file_major_number = res;
    printk( KERN_NOTICE "One: registered character device with major number = %i and minor numbers 0...255\n", device_file_major_number );
    return 0;
}

void unregister_device(void) {
    printk( KERN_NOTICE "One: unregister_device() is called\n" );
    if(device_file_major_number != 0) {
        unregister_chrdev(device_file_major_number, device_name);
    }
}

static int my_init(void) {
    register_device();
    return 0;
}

static void my_exit(void) {
    unregister_device();
    return;
}

// Declare register and unregister command
module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

The Makefile

```
TARGET_MODULE:=one

BUILDSYSTEM_DIR:=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD:=$(shell pwd)
obj-m := $(TARGET_MODULE).o
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910064/how-to-compile-a-linux-kernel-module-using-std-gnu99
ccflags-y := -std=gnu99 -Wno-declaration-after-statement

build:
    # run kernel build system to make module
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDSYSTEM_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    # run kernel build system to cleanup in current directory
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDSYSTEM_DIR) M=$(PWD) clean
    rm -f MOK.priv MOK*.der

key:
    echo "Creating key"
    openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -days 36500 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -subj "/CN=TinmarinoUnsafe/"
    #
    echo "\e[31;1mPlease enter a password you will be asked for on reboot:\e[0m"
    mokutil --import MOK.der
    echo "\e[31;1mNow you must: 1/ reboot, 2/ Select Unroll MOK, 3/ Enter password you previously gave\e[0m"

sign:
    cp one.ko one.ko.bck
    /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 MOK.priv MOK.der one.ko

load:
    insmod ./$(TARGET_MODULE).ko

unload:
    rmmod ./$(TARGET_MODULE).ko

create:
    mknod /dev/one c $(shell cat /proc/devices | grep one$ | cut -d ' ' -f1) 0

delete:
    rm /dev/one

test:
    [ "$(shell xxd -p -l 10 /dev/one)" = "ffffffffffffffffffff" ] \
        && echo "\e[32mSUCCESS\e[0m" \
        || echo "\e[31mFAILED\e[0m"
```

The instalation is long (3min) due to the driver signature enforcement. Froget this part if you disabled it in your UEFI.

1. `git clone https://github.com/tinmarino/dev_one.git DevOne && cd DevOne  # Download`
2. `make build        # Compile`
3. `make key          # Generate key for signing`
4. `sudo make sign    # Sign driver module to permit MOK enforcement (security)`
5. `sudo reboot now   # Reboot and enable Mok`

   1. A blue screen (MOK manager) will appear
   2. Choose "Enroll MOK"
   3. Choose "Continue"
   4. Choose "Yes" (when asked "Enroll the key")
   5. Enter the password you gave at `make sign`
   6. Choose "Reboot" (again)
6. `sudo make load    # Load`
7. `sudo make device  # Create /dev/one`
8. `make test         # Test if all is ok`

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a `/dev/one` without a special device, with a FIFO + `yes`:

```
mkfifo ddfifo
dd if=ddfifo of=<file> iflag=fullblock count=1024 bs=1024 status=progress & yes "" | tr '\n' '\1' > ddfifo
```

`tee` may be used to double the throughput:

```
mkfifo ddfifo
dd if=ddfifo of=<file> iflag=fullblock count=1024 bs=1024 status=progress & yes "" | tr '\n' '\1' | tee ddfifo > ddfifo
```

If you'd like bytes with all bits set to one, swap `'\1'` for `'\377'`.